# How to display API Response in a material-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have component called **List** in that i am displaying data in mat-cards. when i  click on a particular mat-card it is routing to another component called **home** in that component now i am  display the particular mat-card data in mat-card  as shown below:
[image]

But i want to display the same data in **mat-table** Here is the stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-qwd46f?file=src/app/home/home.component.html)**.

Comment: In your home component, this.contact is just an object we can't pass that object to mat-table

Comment: @Sneha Pawar is there any solution for that.

Comment: @Empty_Soul i think i have create table for you but data is add according to you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-2wpytz?file=src/app/home/home.component.html

Comment: Please check forked solution on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-u8nqlx and accept the answer if everything working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare contract as a array

TS

```
contract = [];

// push your response in contract array
this.contact.push(this.dataService.getSelectedCard());
```

please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-ttqvx7?embed=1

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to bind column `id` and `contactName` field with the `matColumnDef`

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="contact" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="contactName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contactName}} </td>
  </ng-container>



  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  contact = [ {id: 1, contactName : "Parmeshwar"}]
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'contactName', 'email'];


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.contact = [this.dataService.getSelectedCard()];

  }

}
```

**Here is [Forked solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-u8nqlx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this markup, it's working as you expect:

**Home Html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Column1">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Column1 </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contactName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Column2">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Column2 </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="Column3">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Column3 </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary"  class="booking-btn"><p>Book Now</p></button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

**Home TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService} from '../data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: any;
  contact = [];
public displayedColumns: string[] = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contact.push(this.dataService.getSelectedCard());
    this.dataSource = this.contact;
  }

}
```

you can also check on link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-2wpytz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can make dataSource an array of objects. You can go through [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-nhtq9q)
**HomeComponent:**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
public contact:Contact[]=[];
public dataSource:Contact[];
public displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'contactName', 'email'];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contact.push(this.dataService.getSelectedCard());
    this.dataSource=this.contact;
  }
}

export interface Contact{
  id: string; 
  contactName:string;
  email:string;
}
```

**home.conponent.html:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

              <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="contactName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contactName}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}} </td>
              </ng-container>
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
```